# CSS performance, class or element styling for repetitive styles?

Tags: performance, css, browser

What is better for website performance regarding css?

I have, for example, repetitive shadow styles to multiple elements. Regarding DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle I can make a class and add it to all elements, that need to have shadows.

What is more performant to the browser? Having a class name on element or couple of styling lines in the element's css.

Having multiple elements with this:

```
element {
  /*
  Some: style;
  Some: style;
  Some: style;
  */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.5);
}
```

or having a class name, then applied to multiple elements:

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(161, 161, 161, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: adding more classes will make css file more longer thus longer download time and harder to maintain. I personally prefer second method since loading mutiple classes from css are optimized by the modern browser.

Comment: "Class" - In addition to others suggestions & unrelated to your question, I would recommend also using `@mixin` functions and call those functions in your element/class. Ex: You could create a function with all the 3 `box-shadow` properties defining them just ONCE & then just call that function multiple times in your CSS.

Comment: common className for the elements that will have that common style/styles is best practice also from performance point of you and also for cleaner and easier to change code